# How to get resolutiion of video stream by url *.m3u8

Tags: java, android, video, resolution, m3u8

I open stream video by url *.m3u8 in Video View
Display of my device is 800x480
**but if** video stream resolution is 1024x768 video stops playing and can be crash of app.

**How to get resolutiion of video steam by url *.m3u8? OR How to resize video stream?**

```
mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(OpenStream.this));
                        mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));
                        mVideoView.requestFocus();
                        mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {


                                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                    mp.start();
                                }
                            });
```

Error:

```
01-29 18:21:12.831: E/MediaPlayer(23281): error (1, -2147483648)
01-29 18:21:12.831: V/MediaPlayer(23281): callback application
01-29 18:21:12.831: V/MediaPlayer(23281): back from callback
01-29 18:21:12.831: E/MediaPlayer(23281): Error (1,-2147483648)
01-29 18:21:12.831: D/VideoView(23281): Error: 1,-2147483648
```

Comment: You can get the video width/height from MediaPlayer, after that you can set them to VideoView SurfaceHolder.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
            mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(OpenStream.this));
                    mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));
                    mVideoView.requestFocus();
                    mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {


                            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                int w = mp.getVideoWidth();
                                int h = mp.getVideoHeight();
                                SurfaceHolder holder = mVideoView.getHolder();
                                holder.setFixedSize(w, h); // Or setup a proportional sizes
                                mp.start();
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: w and h return 0 and 0

Comment: In your case i suppose you should use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener). I'd use MediaPlayer and SurfaceView instead of VideoView. I found a sample for http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/android-mediaplayer-sample-code-walkthrough-on-intel-architecture